# IONIC Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: php, android, angularjs, codeigniter

I was working on an **angularJS**, IONIC project with CI backend.
I was sending parameters to the server using **POST** Method, and receiving it using the CodeIgniter Input class and everything was working OK.

Now that app going to be native Android, the developer should send parameters as JSON array. So I changed my backend API function to receive it like:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$email = $data->email;
```

It works great but the problem now is when I try to access the function using IONIC app I get an php error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
http://192.168.1.122/project/index.php/api/login.
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

on my API I allowed all CORS

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
```

...But I still get the same error.

Can I get any other solution around this point.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin to implements a whitelist policy for navigating the application webview on Cordova 4.0

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

then

```
ionic build <platform>
```

[Source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)